# How do we prove that $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\left(\ln{x}\ln{y}\right)^s\over 1-xy}dxdy=\Gamma^2(1+s)\zeta(2+2s)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

How do we prove that

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\left(\ln{x}\ln{y}\right)^s\over 1-xy}dxdy=\Gamma^2(1+s)\zeta(2+2s)$$

Integrate with respect to x first, let $s=1$

$$\int_{0}^{1}{\ln{y}\ln{x}\over 1-yx}dx$$

$u=\ln{x}\rightarrow xdu=dx$

$$\ln{y}\int_{0}^{\infty}{u\over y-e^{-u}}du$$

I don't think I am in the right track here, any hints please.

Comment: You can do the first integral, obtaining an expression involving $\mbox{Li}_2(\frac{1}{1-y})$.  (a Polylog function of order $2$). But OMG, integrating that expression looks hopeless! I can verify the relation for $s=0$ giving $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ but induction for integer $s$ seems too difficult as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write, for  $s>-1$, $0<xy<1$,
$$
{\left(\ln{x}\ln{y}\right)^s\over 1-xy}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (xy)^n\left(\ln{x}\ln{y}\right)^s
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\left(\ln{x}\ln{y}\right)^s\over 1-xy}dxdy&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (xy)^n\left(\ln{x}\ln{y}\right)^sdxdy
\\\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\int_{0}^{1}x^n\left(-\ln{x}\right)^sdx\right)\left(\int_{0}^{1}y^n\left(-\ln{y}\right)^sdy\right)
\\\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\int_{0}^{1}x^n\left(-\ln{x}\right)^sdx\right)^2
\\\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{(n+1)^{s+1}}\right)^2
\\\\&=\Gamma^2(s+1)\:\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2s+2}}
\\\\&=\Gamma^2(1+s)\:\zeta(2+2s)
\end{align}
$$ as announced.

The interchange between $\int$ and $\sum$ may be justified by the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: Thank you @Olivier Oloa I understood all the steps. Nice answer.

Comment: Nice......( +1)